# When rotating element it placed on the fixed element

Tags: html, css

When I rotate something with css `transform` property it placed on the fixed element. In this example when I scroll the page, I want `.child` div be **on** all elements. `.two` works fine and goes behind child, but `.one` is placed on it.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.child {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.one {
  text-align:left;
  transform: rotate(2deg);
}
br {
  display: block;
  line-height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
  </div>

</div>
<p style='height:200px'></p>
<p class="one">ONE</p>
<p class="two">TWO</p>
<p style='height:700px'></p>
```

Comment: So you're saying you want to make `.one` goes behind `.child` like `.two`?

Comment: @OzikJarwo Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give `z-index` to the fixed element, so it will be on all elements.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.child {
  z-index:1; /* this */
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.one {
  text-align:left;
  transform: rotate(2deg);
}
br {
  display: block;
  line-height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
  </div>

</div>
<p style='height:200px'></p>
<p class="one">ONE</p>
<p class="two">TWO</p>
<p style='height:700px'></p>
```

Learn more about the `z-index` property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).